# react show job progress

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making requests inside a loop and would like to show its progress on a div:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Job() {
  const [part, setPart] = useState(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  async function executeJob() {
    const N_PARTS = 10;
    for (let i = 0; i < N_PARTS; i++) {
      setPart(i);
      setMessage(`Current part: ${part}`);
      await axios.post(`/parts/${i}/doit`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{message}</div>
      <button onClick={executeJob}>Execute</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I run this, the requests were made correctly, but it doesn't display `message` correctly. I suspect that I can't set states sequentially this way and have to put it inside an effect. I'm new to using React hooks, please let me know the correct way.

Comment: need `doPart()` code also.

Comment: I've changed it to just making a post request now.

Comment: edited again to have a repro. This time, `message` state is computed from the `part` state.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple example.

```
export default function App() {

  const [ part, setPart] = React.useState(0);

  async function execute(){
    for await(let i of new Array(10).fill(0)){
      setPart((prev)=>prev+1);
      console.log(i);
      await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api`).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      })
    }

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {part}</h1>
      <button onClick={execute}>Excute</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the same example in `codesandbox`

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cannon-srppr

you can use `for-loop` with async-await.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: After my last edit, I guess  my question has now become how do I compute `message` based on `part`. For example, if I want to display an ongoing log to show the progress history. I would then append all the messages from the API into it.

Comment: @pckben you can use `array` instead.

Comment: It's more for my understanding now how to do something simple as ```setPart(i); setMessage(message + '\n' + `part ${i}`)```. Also, in your answer, why do I have to make the for loop async? My array is static and is not an async iterable.

Comment: @pckben have you ever been tried to retype your code base on my example?

Comment: I tried in the sandbox, if I replace the `for await` with `for`, the result is still the same. On the other hand, if I add a reference of `{part}` in the message construction, then it doesn't update correctly in each iteration: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-forest-vquru